# Ubuntu not installing on a 32bit system

Tags: 12.04, installation

[image]

As you can see, I have a 32x OS, and it works fine, however, when I run the wubi.exe it fails to do anything. My computer processes the .exe and then does absolutely nothing.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly recommend not to use wubi anymore to install Ubuntu. newer versions of Ubuntu will not include the wubi anymore and in my experience it gives a lot of trouble. please follow [these instructions](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-desktop-long-term-support) instead.